# Cakephp SELECT recursive associtations fields by condition

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

This is going to be a long shot, but I have been staring at this for longer then I should have... I have a structure setup like this:

```
C (hasMany) B (hasMany) A
1           1           1
2           2           2
3           3           3
4           4           4
```

Where each character is a table, and each number a field of said table record. Field 1 is the primary key called 'id'. My function only takes a single argument, lets call it $X. The following is what should happen:

- Find the first record in table C, where field 3 has value $X
- Find the first record in table B, where field 2 has the value of A record's field 1
- select fields 3 and 4 in table A of all records, where field 2 has the value of B record's field 1

Working with CakePHP has been a blessing with it's more then decent documentation, but beside my lack of properly understanding associations, I find it extremely difficult to make this work recursivly. What am i dong wrong here?

So far ive tried a few variations of the following:

```
$tableC->find('all')
     ->select(['val1'=>'A.3',
               'val2'=>'A.4',
              ]) 
     ->where(['C.3 = ' => $X])
     ->innerJoinWith('B')                                       
     ->innerJoinWith('A')                                       
     ->toList()
     ;
```

I can get whatever values I want from the B table, but anything further then that is where I start getting errors like:

> The A association is not defined on C.

Is there anyone that could shed some light on this? Im using CakePHP 3.9.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that your lack of properly understanding associations is precisely why you are struggling with this. And your obfuscation of column names as "val1" and "A.3" is not helping us to understand what you are trying to actually accomplish.

Comment: I am well aware of my lack of proper understanding on these associations im afraid. I have been reading those documentations for the past 2 days and It doesnt wanna click with me. Regarding the values, val1 and val2 are the aliased I wanna store the values of (table)A.(field)3 and 4 in, so the returned list eventually only has an array whatever there was those fields A.3 and A.4

Comment: Need Table A,B and C Model Code for understanding of problem statement?

Comment: As already mentioned, these made up names make it unnecessarily complicated for people to wrap their heads around the problem, so please use your original names whenever possible! That being said, it sounds like you maybe want to use `innerJoinWith('B.A')`, ie use a dot notated path to denote nested associations to join in.

Comment: Ah okay, my bad. I thought I explained the situation well enough. How would one share table structures on SO?